# glDrawArray does not draw anything until ccDrawLine is called

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a total beginner when it comes to game development. I make my first steps with Cocos2D right now I have a strange problem I just don't understand.

I try to create CCRenderTexture in order to create a dynamic texture for a scrolling background. Right now it's should only render a yellow background with some black stripes on it.

So I wrote the following to accomplish that:

```
- (CCSprite *)debugTextureWidth:(float)textureWidth textureHeight:(float)textureHeight {

  // Create a texture and set the background color to yellow
  CCRenderTexture *debugTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureWidth height:textureHeight];
  [debugTexture beginWithClear:1.0f g:204.0f /255.0f b:0 a:1.0f];

  // ccDrawLine(ccp(0, 0), ccp(200.0f, 200.0f));

  // Draw some diagonal stripes
  int nStripes = ((arc4random() %4) +1) *2;
  CGPoint vertices[nStripes *6];
  ccColor4F colors[nStripes *6];

  int nVertices = 0;
  float x1 = -textureHeight;
  float x2;
  float y1 = textureHeight;
  float y2 = 0;
  float dx = textureWidth /nStripes *2;
  float stripeWidth = dx /2;

  ccColor4F stripeColor = (ccColor4F){1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f};

  for (int i = 0; i < nStripes; i++) {
    x2 = x1 + textureHeight;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
    colors[nVertices++] = stripeColor;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x1 +stripeWidth, y1);
    colors[nVertices++] = stripeColor;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
    colors[nVertices++] = stripeColor;

    vertices[nVertices] = vertices[nVertices -2];
    colors[nVertices++] = stripeColor;

    vertices[nVertices] = vertices[nVertices -2];
    colors[nVertices++] = stripeColor;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x2 +stripeWidth, y2);
    colors[nVertices++] = stripeColor;
    x1 += dx;
  }

  [self setShaderProgram:[[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionColor]];

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_Color);

  [self.shaderProgram use];
  [self.shaderProgram setUniformsForBuiltins];

  // CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

  glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
  glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, colors);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);

  [debugTexture end];

  return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:debugTexture.sprite.texture];
}
```

This gives me something like this:

[image: CCRenderTexture fail]

Now comes the strange part. As soon as I uncomment the ccDrawLine instruction on line 6, I get the following:

[image: CCRenderTexture half win]

Now it draws the line and the stripes I wanted in the first place.

I searched a few hours in order to understand this but all I got from my search was something like "You have to add a shader" which I think I do.

As I said, I'm completely new to this whole OpenGL thing. Please be patient with me here. :-) I really want to understand this. So if you have a solution for my problem and/or a good pointer for where to look for a good read on this topic, please let me know.

Thanks and Greets,
Thomas

Comment: check the ccDrawLine function and see what it does that you don't

Comment: I did that. When I copy and paste that into my code, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a simple typo.

There is nothing wrong with the code per sé. But I just used the wrong calls to setup the shader.

This part is wrong:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_Color);

[self.shaderProgram use];
[self.shaderProgram setUniformsForBuiltins];

// CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
```

First of all I call the wrong methods with the wrong parameters. I guess the auto-completion fooled me here. The correct calls have to look like this:

```
ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);
ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);

CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
```

The rest of the code stays the same.

To be totally honest I don't really understand what I'm doing here. So, I'm still in for good OpenGLES 2.0 tutorials. Ideally how to use it with cocos2d-iphone. :-)

Thanks and Greets,
Thomas